# transform animation function from jQuery into vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replicate a simon game that I code a times ago in a bootcamp with pure jQuery and I want to transform it into a vanilla JS. I know ofcourse is most simple the code in jQuery, but I want to get better in the "hard way" and not always do all my work always in frameworks.

So this is my old code with jQuery, it's really simple and easy to read, but everytime I achive the result of add the class and remove it, it get added to all the elements.

```js
    function animatePress(currentColor) {
  $("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#" + currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
  }, 100);
}
```

And this is my attemp to get the same without using jQuery.

```js
function animatePress() {
  let greenBtn = document.getElementById("green");
  let yellowBtn = document.getElementById("yellow");
  let redBtn = document.getElementById("red");
  let blueBtn = document.getElementById("blue");
  let allButtons = [greenBtn, yellowBtn, redBtn, blueBtn];

  allButtons.forEach(function (e) {
    e.classList.add("pressed");
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.classList.remove("pressed");
    }, 100);
  });
}
```

Comment: Your original code passes in `currentColor` so it only applies it to the button/color that the function receives.  Your new function rips through `allButtons` and so everything is updated.  Make your new function accept the button to be changed as a param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation from the jQuery version to pure javascript

```
function animatePress(currentColor) {
  const button = document.querySelector('#' + currentColor);
  button.classList.add("pressed");
  setTimeout(function(){
    button.classList.remove("pressed")
  }, 100);
}
```

The `es6` version :

```
const animatePress = currentColor => {
  const button = document.querySelector(`#${currentColor}`);
  button.classList.add("pressed");
  setTimeout(() => button.classList.remove("pressed"), 100);
}
```